# How to know if a point is on linestring or near one (<0.01units) using GeoPandas

Tags: point, line, geopandas, maps, points-to-line

I want to know if a point intersects/touches/on the line/linestring or if the point is less than 0.01 mts (units) from linestring.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lines_gdf = gpd.read_file('line.shp')
points_gdf =  gpd.read_file('points.shp')

pip_mask = points_gdf.intersects(lines_gdf.loc[0, 'geometry'])
```

post running the script I can see all the data in pip_mask is false.
So if intersects/touches doest work is there any way to check if the point is <0.01 mts form the line?

[image: For reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

maxDist = 0.3
lines = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/lines.shp')
points = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/points_nearby.shp')

lines['savedIndex'] = lines.index
points['savedIndex'] = points.index

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265613/pandas-cross-join-no-columns-in-common
points['tmp'] = 1 
lines['tmp'] = 1
df = pd.merge(points, lines, on=['tmp'], suffixes=('_points', '_lines'))

df['dist'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.geometry_points.distance(row.geometry_lines), axis=1) #Apply distance method between each point and line
match = df.loc[(0 <= df.dist) & (df.dist <= maxDist)][['savedIndex_points', 'savedIndex_lines']] #Select rows with chosen distance

#match
#   savedIndex_points  savedIndex_lines      dist
#5                  1                 1  0.015852
#9                  2                 1  0.285490
```

So my second point (index 1) and second line are 0.016 m apart...

Then you can merge the results back to your points if you want to:

```
points = pd.merge(left=points, right=match[['savedIndex_points','dist']], left_index=True, right_on='savedIndex_points', how='left')
del(points['savedIndex_points'])
points.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/points_nearby_analyzed.shp')
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot, but one thing to consider is if the data sets for both points and lines are increasing then merging on 'tmp' column is going to take lot of calculations(exponential increase). Probably we can use ballTree() to mitigate the issue. By the way I solved the issue using different approach, I will paste my answer below. Please check once for any improvements.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the below approach, as the issue is the point is not exactly on the line I used buffer to increase the size of the point, basically making it to a circle and thus intersecting the line.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
lines_gdf = gpd.read_file('line.shp')
points_gdf =  gpd.read_file('points.shp')
    
points_gdf['geometry'] = points_gdf.geometry.buffer(5)
join = gpd.sjoin(lines_gdf, points_gdf, how = 'inner', op ='intersects')
```

with this join has the required data

Comment: `op` parameter is deprecated and got replaced by `predicate`: `join = gpd.sjoin(lines_gdf, points_gdf, how = 'inner', predicate='intersects')`